# MySQL: Missing results

Tags: mysql

A simple MySQL query is returning a result set that is missing results.

```
SELECT users.uid, users.firstname, users.lastname, jobs_apps.read_app, jobs_apps.datetime
FROM jobs_apps 
JOIN users ON users.uid = jobs_apps.uid 
WHERE jobs_apps.job_id = '90'
```

This returns a 29 rows. If I run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs_apps WHERE job_id = '90'
```

I get 31 rows.

The 2 missing results have a value of 0 in the 'read_app' instead of 1.

What could be causing this?

P.S.: I tried running the original query and changing the SELECT clause to simply "SELECT * " and I still only get 29 out of the 31 rows back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an `OUTER JOIN` in your query

ie;

```
SELECT users.uid, users.firstname, users.lastname, jobs_apps.read_app, jobs_apps.datetime
FROM jobs_apps 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN users ON users.uid = jobs_apps.uid 
WHERE jobs_apps.job_id = '90'
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Still only getting 29 rows back. This is weird.

Comment: Just try `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT` just for the sake of testing and see what happens..?

Comment: Same result. However, if I run that query and add read_app = '0' to the where clause, the left join returns the 2 missing rows with the firstname / lastname / uid columns returning NULL.

Comment: That means that there are no records in your user table which corresponds to the job_app table. Outer join should return those rows nevertheless there are corresponding rows or not..! 
Try the `outer join` without the `ON` clause and specify that delimiter as an `AND` under `WHERE` and see what happens..

Comment: Great. I just uncovered a much bigger issue because of this. I just realised I have some missing user records. This is gonna be fun to deal with. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! it is always fun to deal with programming issues :-)